# How to handle LocalDate/LocalTime in code of JDK 6

Tags: java, date, java-8, java-6, localdate

I'm writing a library and it has some code like:

```
    public void foo(Object value){
      if(value instanceof Date){
          ...
      }else if(value instanceof Calendar){
          ...
      }...
    }
```

The code is supposed can be running on at least JDK6.
So, I have to code and compile on JRE6. 
But, in case, if a user works on JDK8 and passing a LocalDate/LocalTime object to the method.

How should I handle the case?

LocalDate/LocalTime can't compile on JRE6.

Or, I have to use two version of code? One for JDK6, and another for JDK8?

Comment: Certainly you can't use your JDK 8 types in your JDK 6 code base. However, you may consider using JDK 6 types in your JDK 8 code base. For example, you could consider using [310-backports](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which basically provides the same set of classes in JDK 8 `java.time` API for applications running in earlier versions of Java. Unfortunately, this also means changing your JDK8-based APIs to use this backports.

Comment: @EdwinDalorzo Thanks a lot for your quick response.  I can't switch my code to JDK8 for compatible reason.  Based on your comment, I'm now thinking about not support JDK8 objects in my code. And may force user to do some converting job. Bad ideas :-(

Comment: It also depends on what kind of value you want to extract from the date/time-related object. You could let JDK8 users inject their own Strategy to extract the value into your class and that strategy object would deal with the type conversion (a Strategy would be an interface that has a method to extract the type of value you want. In java 8 they can be easily implemented with lambdas or method references)

Comment: FYI, in Java 9 it is possible to build [Multi-release JAR Files](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/238). I didn't try it though.

Comment: @DidierL Wonderful! So, jar can have the similar function as nuget package   for .Net . Thanks.

Comment: Ugh. This is a rare case where preprocessors would work to create JDK6 and JDK8 compatible versions from the same code base... Excuse me while I go wash my mouth out with soap just for mentioning it.

Comment: You can try splitting your library into two parts - core and jre-specific. The responsibility of the latter is to adapt jre-specific types for use by your core library.